# Viewport Shading Is Bugged (Blender 3.0)

Tags: 3d-view

I've been trying to learn blender but recently I encountered this weird issue with my viewport shading. Is this normal?[image]

Comment: That looks like a graphics driver problem. Is your graphics card compatible with blender 3.0 and have you updated to the latest drivers?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JohnEason I think that's my problem. Thank you for your help.